# Excel macro not working because of incorrect proxy settings

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, proxy

**Problem description:**

My colleague created an Excel-based application some month ago which runs fine on his notebook. Strangely, the same workbook won't work on anyone else's PC. When run inside a virtual Windows 10 session not connected to AD, the workbook also works as expected. We are all using company computers connected to the same AD servers so I can't see why the code works on his machine and not on other machines.

**What I found out so far:**

- The problem originates from a proxy setting that does not make sense at all. I work for a company in Germany that is Swiss-based, the currently used proxy in Excel shows up as a Chinese firewall of our company.
- There is no server set up in Windows settings (Windows 7 still in use).
- `Netsh` does not show any proxy:

> PS C:> netsh winhttp show proxy
>
> Current WinHTTP proxy settings:
>
> Direct access (no proxy server).

- browser internet traffic is not using any proxy

I assume that there is some setting specifically set up for Excel that I just can't find and I don't have any more ideas where to look.

**Code**

The Excel macro creates a WinHttpRequest object without changing any additional settings as can be seen in this code excerpt:

```
Set httpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
httpReq.setTimeouts -1, -1, -1, 600000
httpReq.Open "GET", url, False
httpReq.send request
myResponse = httpReq.ResponseText
```

The `url` is not pointing to the proxy server but contains a local IP address.

Would appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting the ip to use with the proxy arg?

Comment: Not yet, would you have a code example how to include this as part of the above script?

Comment: Thanks, will try this tomorrow and give you feedback. But this still wouldn't solve the problem entirely, I really want to understand how a group policy / Windows setting / Excel setting may be set to only influence how Excel connects to remote HTTP servers.

Comment: that might make a better question in one of the other tags/sites

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I did check though if other communities might fit but even the more general communities like Serverfault also don't seem to contain any sources of information for this type. I assume that your recommendation would solve the problem so I'll try it tomorrow and if that works, I'll let you know so you can create an answer to this question.

Comment: @QHarr I haven't found any differences in group policies or user settings but thanks for offering to help. I'll try the proxy suggestion you provided yesterday and see if that's a solution.

Comment: @QHarr I solved it by setting connection to direct: `httpReq.SetProxy(1)`. Would you phrase an answer based on your comments so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter proxy settings. For example,

```
httpReq.SetProxy(1)
```

This option can be used to specify that all HTTP and HTTPS servers should be accessed directly.

Addit info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760236(v%3Dvs.85)) though js version